# Delete a merge commit from git

Tags: git

I have a merge commit on a Git repository that I want to delete.

How to really delete a commit from git?

I mean DELETE a commit that has no commits after it. I just do not want it clogging the history (and occuping disk space).

Please do not answer with anything like "git -i rebase" as you can not use rebase to delete a commit with no child commits.

```
0 <-this is now HEAD and master
|
|  this is a different merge between the same branches, master and hotfix-1
| /
0   0 <-THIS is the commit I want to DELETE (incorrect merge)
|\ /|
| X |
|/ \|
0   0
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   0
|   |
|   |
|   |
0   0 <- this is start of branch hotfix-1
|  /
| /
|/
0
|
```

EDIT:

Please do not answer with anything like "git reset --hard HEAD~1" as that **does not delete the commit** for merge commits:

```
user@host /dir/subdir (master)
$ git checkout b605a0dd5e12e65081a2d8ffe7c905617b210605
Note: checking out 'b605a0dd5e12e65081a2d8ffe7c905617b210605'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at b605a0d... Merge branch 'hotfix-1'

user@host /dir/subdir ((b605a0d...))
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1 ## TRYING TO DELETE COMMIT
HEAD is now at 65e8158 Some commit message

user@host /dir/subdir ((Some tag))
$ git checkout b605a0dd5e12e65081a2d8ffe7c905617b210605
Previous HEAD position was 65e8158... Some commit message
HEAD is now at b605a0d... Merge branch 'hotfix-1'

user@host /dir/subdir ((b605a0d...)) ## COMMIT STILL THERE
$
```

Comment: You could nuke it via `git reset --hard HEAD~1`.  But if the hotfix branch gets deleted, and nothing else is referring to that commit, it would be garbage collected anyway at some point.

Comment: Ugh, bit of a horrid problem, never seen a way to delete, only to play smoke and mirrors. Branch from the point / sha / commit before the one you do not want, and make that your new working branch, delete the branch with the bad commit, then branch your new one again back to the same name as the one you have deleted - you have in effect deleted that commit. Only works though if no one else has branched / pulled from the branch with the bad commit

Comment: I do not understand the confusion here: OP already undid the previous merge and redid it properly which is now in the master branch. There is no need to reset a branch or to rewrite the history because it’s already correct. It’s just that they want to get rid of the remainders of the original merge commit.

Comment: I should have added "no answers with reset --hard HEAD~1" as this is a merge commit, but I supposed it was obvious.

Comment: `reset` works fine regardless of merges, and `rebase` can drop a commit that has no children; so it would seem you're misinformed about both of those commands.  It is true that neither one of them *ever* deletes a commit.  (They move refs and, in the case of rebase, create "rewritten" commits; but they don't delete anything.)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger performing either 'git rebase -i master' or 'git rebase -i hotfix-1' does not show the merge commit itself, so it can not be dropped. I just tried it

Comment: @Envite - That's because the commit is not in the history of either of those refs; it has nothing to do with whether the commit is a merge or whether it has children.

Answer (score 2):

If the commit has nothing referencing it, e.g. branches or tags, then the commit is unreachable and effectively removed from the history. It will be eventually garbage collected and physically removed from the repository database.

You can run force a garbage collection run by running `git gc --prune=now`, so that should get rid of the unreachable objects.

Note that you generally do not need to do this as the unreachable commits are not sent anywhere, and only exist temporarily in your repository. Keeping unreachable commits around will help you to restore commits in case something went wrong and branch pointers went missing. So unless you actually have memory issues, I personally wouldn’t recommend you to prune your repository.

Comment: I have run 'git gc --prune=now' but that weird merge commit has not disappeared. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Envite How do you know that it has not disappeared? Where do you see it?

Answer (score 1):

As poke correctly informed you (your dismissive response notwithstanding) a commit with nothing referencing it can be garbage-collected, and there is no "more direct" command to delete the commit than `gc`.

The problem, of course, is that something probably *is* still referencing that commit.  That "something" is the ref log.

The vanity of insisting on removing all traces of a mistake is a waste of effort.  The problem (such as it is) will go away on its own over time (because the reflog will expire and then gc will catch up with the commit), and in the mean time a single merge commit is not even remotely likely to occupy significant disk space.

That doesn't mean it's impossible, but it comes at a cost.  You can either

(A) Wipe out your reflogs and then run `gc`.  Of course you'll have to make sure that *any* reflog that could point at the offending commit is discarded.  That's *at least* the `HEAD` reflog and the reflog for the branch on which the merge occurred.  You'll likely lose useful reflog history in the process.

or

(B) Create a fresh clone.  Assuming you fixed the merge before pushing, then the merge commit shouldn't be present on origin.  Any fresh clone would then not contain the commit.  (They also will not have any of your reflog history, so this really is equivalent to (A).)